# javascript iterating over a collection and populating a set of values

Tags: javascript

[image]i have a collection of dates (including time) i need to iterate over the collection and plug in the right dates and times according to the date that the user inputs.  at the end of the html document obviously i have  javascript; the js will iterate over the table and plug in the right dates

so if one date happens to be before today the date counters will show negative (i will take care of zero-ing it out later) but if the date is in the future the timers should show the right times..

the problem i am facing with this application is that the dates are showing the same for the collection of dates.  so it doesnt matter if i have 100 dates in my collection or 1 the timer will show the same dates on the timer.

i am not executing the for each collection the right way.. and i am not grabbing the classNames right either.  i  guess thats why the dates in the timer are showing the same.  so its grabbing the first date the js can grab and populating all the timers with the same date

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <meta name="Author" content="" />

</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="for-sale-heading">
                    <h4>End Date:&nbsp;</h4>
                    <h5 class="time">04-30-22 15:00:00</h5>
                </td>
                <td class="for-sale-heading">
                    <div class="clock">
                        <div>
                            <span class="day"></span>
                            <div class="local-date">Days</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="hour"></span>
                            <div class="local-date">Hours</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="minute"></span>
                            <div class="local-date">Minutes</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="second"></span>
                            <div class="local-date">Seconds</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="closed"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="for-sale-heading">
                    <h4>End Date:&nbsp;</h4>
                    <h5 class="time">04-30-20 15:00:00</h5>
                </td>
                <td class="for-sale-heading">
                    <div class="clock">
                        <div>
                            <span class="day"></span>
                            <div class="local-date">Days</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="hour"></span>
                            <div class="local-date">Hours</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="minute"></span>
                            <div class="local-date">Minutes</div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span class="second"></span>
                            <div class="local-date">Seconds</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="closed"></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </section>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            const timeClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("time");
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(timeClasses, function(timeClass) {
                const x = setInterval(function() {
                    // const innerHtml1 = $('.time').html();
                    const innerHtml = timeClass.innerHTML;

                    const deadline = new Date(innerHtml.toString()).getTime();
                    const now = new Date().getTime();
                    const t = deadline - now;
                    const days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                    const hours = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                    const minutes = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                    const seconds = Math.floor((t % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
                    const spanElements = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
                    Array.prototype.forEach.call(spanElements, function(spanElement) {
                        // console.log(el.className);
                        // console.log(el.getElementsByClassName);
                        switch (spanElement.className) {
                            case "day":
                                //                            console.log("day");
                                $('.day').html(days); // or use el.innerHTML = days;
                                break;
                            case "hour":
                                //                            console.log("hour");
                                $('.hour').html(hours); // or use el.innerHTML = hours;
                                break;
                            case "minute":
                                //                            console.log("minute");
                                $('.minute').html(minutes); // or use el.innerHTML = minutes;
                                break;
                            case "second":
                                //                            console.log("second");
                                $('.second').html(seconds); // or use el.innerHTML = seconds;
                                break;
                        }
                    });

                }, 1000);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### numbers flashing

You are using the setInterval method with a delay of zero miliseconds, it tries to refresh the number as fast as it can (why the numbers appear to be flashing).

```
const x = setInterval(function() {
    // code here,
    0 // <-- delay
});
```

If you set the delay to a larger number (e.g. 1000 miliseconds) the numbers stop flashing

```
const x = setInterval(function() {
    // code here,
    1000 // <-- delay
});
```

### numbers being the same

You are referencing the classname for setting the numbers in the html

```
$('.day').html(days);
```

This won't work because the elements for each date have the same class names, you need to use ID's to reference to the correct element.

See this JSFiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/2qf30v9m/

Comment: thank you for that i fixed it but that didn't help the main problem i have.. i guess it was my mistake i updated the question after fixing the delay..  i am having a problem in populating the dates in all the timer.. as it stands the timer is grabbing the 1st time it sees and populates for the whole collection instead of populating each of the class collections

Comment: I understand the question now, I updated my answer, hope this helps.

Comment: yea i thought about that but thats too much work if i have alot of clocks i have to keep incrementing those ids in the html; client doesnt know html; i need something like an if statement and a break that will short circuit the forEach loop

Comment: In that case you can target the index of the span element using ".eq()"
[updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/60ynqb53/)

Comment: Peter you are very patient but there is another problem here.. its showing the right times for each of the collection but now the clock is not ticking anymore..  its just stuck looking or mocking me...  this is my second day tinkering with this.. you are faster than me .. do you have any more suggestions??

Comment: Looks like I put the count in the wrong place, [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/b1sg7jt0/4/)

Comment: works great.  thanks alot.  but can you please explain to me why its working i still don't understand what the increment-er is doing .. ... you have put too much time into this if i could give you more +++ i would.. thanks alot

Comment: "$('.day')" return an array of elements that have the class "day", in your code you did not specify an index, so it applies the html to all elements in the array. By providing an index it only applies the html to the single element. The incrementer is used to specify the index.

Comment: ok thanks.  i thought that might be a reason being so many class="day" i had tried something like this document.getElementsByClassName("day")[0].innerHTML = days; before but that didn't work.. i have never seen an array being called like this before $('.day').eq(count).html(days) i guess thats jquery way of calling the array.  again i thank you very much .